# Bounded Operator Norm: Special Element

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, banach-spaces

Given a Banach spaces $X$ and $Y$.

Consider a bounded operator:
$$T:X\to Y:\quad\|T\|<\infty$$

Then theres an element:
$$\|Tx\|=\|T\|\cdot\|x\|\quad(x\neq0)$$
Does it always exist?

Comment: Do you mean $\: T : X\to Y \;$? $\;\;\;\;$

Comment: @RickyDemer: Yep, thanks for noting.

Comment: For a Hilbert space, I believe this is true: there exists such $x$ iff $T^{\star}Tx = \|T\|^{2}x$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How about this: define $T : \ell^1 \to \ell^1$ by

$$T(a_1, a_2, a_3, \cdots, a_n, \cdots) = (0, (1-1/2)a_2, (1-1/3)a_3, \cdots, (1-1/n)a_n, \cdots)$$

Then $$||T|| = \sup_{||x|| = 1} ||Tx|| = \sup_n (1-1/n) = 1$$

However, for all non-zero $x \in \ell^1$, $||Tx|| < ||x|| = ||T|| \cdot ||x||$.

Comment: Similarly for any $\ell^p$, $1 \le p < \infty$.